# MapView fix not compling

Tags: android

I get the following error with my MapView: "CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized"

Many posts out there suggest adding: `MapsInitializer.initialize(this);` but now IDE is telling me: "GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException is never thrown"

My code is below:

XML:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

And code to run it:

```
    mapView = (MapView) header.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    map = mapView.getMap();

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

Comment: You need to add calls to `mapView.onCreate()` and `mapView.onResume()`. Also, remove the try/catch block and just call the initializer without it.

Comment: Many thanks. Do you mind a bit more details. what do you mean about adding calls to `onCreate()` and `onResume()`?

Comment: OK I got it to work following your comment but I don't understand what those lines are doing and I never like doing stuff I don't understand! :)

Comment: Sorry I was running around and didn't have time to write it all out. I added an answer that hopefully explains it well enough.

Comment: Yes it's great. Many thanks... The hard life of an iOS man in the world of android :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you are getting a compiler warning because `MapsInitializer.initialize(this);` does not throw a `GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException`. So by surrounding it with a try/catch, you are introducing unreachable code in the `catch`.

Now the reason that you need to call `onCreate` and `onResume` is that there are lifecycle events logic that Google needs to perform in order for the `MapView` to function properly. If you were using a `MapFragment` this is taken care of for you in the background. Ideally, you put these method calls in their respective Activity/Fragment methods. So call `mapView.onCreate()` in your `onCreate` method, `mapView.onResume()` in `onResume`, etc. You should also add calls to `onPause` and `onDestroy` as well.

Hope that clears things up for you. Feel free to follow up with any questions about this.